# I have deleted all launcher apps, how to fix?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

i have sgh-t989  and i have installed a custom rom beanstalk 4.4.2. mistakenly deleted all launchers now i cant use home, tried to restart phone doesnt fix it. now i cant even on my phone. i cant go to recovery mode because my home button is dead. is there any way i can go to recovery mode using pc because when i connect andriod to pc using usb cable it shows all the data i have so i can reinstall my rom. i tried other methods but nothing works because my home button suks. plz help

Comment: Turn on phone, you should be able to pull down status bar, go to settings>security and allow apps from unknown sources. Then enable Bluetooth and from other phone send .APK file of any launcher you can find apk files on apkmirror and when you receive file you two on it from notifications and install. Other way is to get to settings and enable usb debugging then connect to PC and use ADB command "adb reboot recovery" your phone will reboot to recovery. Voila! P.s. change title of question.

Comment: 1) I had a T989 myself, and it uses a soft home key, so it doesn't matter and you should be able to go to recovery mode; 2) Even though you don't have a launcher, status bar should still be accessible as ЈеднорукиКрстивоје said.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a launcher. That's the problem. But you still have access to status bar, which is a part of System UI. So here comes the 1<sup>st</sup> solution:

- Boot your phone as normal, then unlock it. You should see a blank screen with only your wallpaper (or black screen) **with a normally-functioning status bar**.
- Drop down the status bar and there should be an entry to your Settings app. Tap it to open settings.
- Turn on USB debugging and connect your phone to a computer.
- From your computer, download an APK of a launcher app of your choice. Place it somewhere and grab an `adb` executable.
- Open a command prompt (terminal) and enter

  ```
  adb push name-of-your.apk /sdcard/
  adb install /sdcard/name-of-your.apk
  ```
- Wait for installation to complete. If it takes more than a minute, reboot your phone and it should be OK. You will be prompted to select the default launcher app with only 1 option.

Alternatively as suggested by *Једноруки Крстивоје*, as a 2<sup>nd</sup> solution, you can send the APK via bluetooth and install it from the notification bar.

Comment: I was going to answer exactly this :) I would suggest to add some links to launchers like [Pixel Launcher](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/pixel-launcher/), [Google Now Launcher](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-now-launcher/) and to [SDK Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you signed into your Google Account on the phone? If so, on your PC go to https://play.google.com/store and find a launcher (I would recommend Nova Launcher or Action Launcher) and click into it, then click the `Install` button, if the button says `Installed` already just click it again, then select your device from the list and click `Install` and your your app should be installed shortly.

Once it completes installing, unlock your device and press the Home key and you should be brought to the first time use screen for the launcher you installed and have access back into your device to enable USB debugging or anything else you need to do to reinstall your ROM.

Note that I believe Nova Launcher is installed with Beanstalk (at least some versions) as it's default launcher, so if you install that from the Play Store you are likely in the same condition as you would be in reflashing the ROM except the launcher will not be installed as a system app (which you could fix with apps like Titanium Backup).

Comment: The OP said he installed a custom ROM. We have no guarantee that he's got Play Store on his device so this may not work in some cases.

Comment: @iBug You are correct, but it is a simple alternative to solving the problem if Gapps are installed the the device is signed into a Google Account, and has network connectivity of course.

Comment: Too many prerequisites...

Comment: @iBug Except they are common ones that are more likely to be in place than not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have google now installed you can easily open app like play store and install a launcher from there

update -

1. speak "ok google"
2. "open play store"
3. search for launcher
4. download any launcher
5. open it and enjoy

if google now is not enabled

1. open notification panel
2. open setting and enable google now hot word
3. proceed with above steps